# type or element in WSDL types section

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

It seems that I have some options when defining types in a wsdl `<types/>` section.

If I define a type (simple or complex) then I can reference that type like this: `<message> <part name="x" type="tns:myTypeName"/>`

If I define an element in the `<types/>` section as an `<element/>` then I can reference it like this: `<message> <part name="x" element="myElementName"/>`

Both options seem to pass validation.  I have seen some examples with the element approach, but I don't see anything wrong with the type approach. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is an option, but they have different meanings.

If you use element, you're specifying the name, namespace, and type of the element in the message. If you're specifying `type`, then you are only specifying the type. In practice, then, the `part` in the WSDL `message` element specifies the name of the element, but the namespace is then ambiguous.

This is a frequent source of incompatibility. The [WS-I BP 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html) specification specifies to use `element`, not `type`, because this prevents the ambiguity.

---

I haven't read the WS-I BP 1.1 document for a few years now. I now remember that it's more complicated than I had recalled.

You must use `type` if you are creating an RPC/Literal service. You must use `element` if you are creating a Document/Literal service. There are restrictions on the use of `namespace` attributes in the WSDL in both cases, for the reason I specified: to prevent ambiguity.

See, among others, [4.7.21. Namespaces for Children of Part Accessors](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html#Namespaces_for_Children_of_Part_Accessors)

One thing that's implied by the very existence of the WS-I: don't create a WSDL by hand, expecting schema validation to produce a valid service for you. Instead, use the tools provided by the web service framework you've chosen. This at least reduces the number of *kinds* of ambiguity you'll produce, to one set per framework.

Comment: Looks like we found answers at about the same time.  Is my answer below correct, as far as type reference limits to one part per message?  Also, what about RPC/Encoded?

Comment: No, your answer is backwards. Document/Literal is limited to one part, but you can have one part per parameter for RPC/Literal. Also, WS-I BP 1.1 prohibits the Encoded formats.

Comment: How are you reading that? According to the following article document/literal can have multiple parts per message: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/
 although according to this article multiple type specified parts are allowed as well

Comment: You may have noticed I've been referring to the WS-I BP 1.1 document, and not to IBM.

Comment: I see. So anything in the WS-I specification would trump any specification in the IBM article or the w3c wsdl 1.1 specification? Would anything break if one didn't follow the profile?

Comment: I recommend you find out more about what the WS-I (Interoperability) organization is about, then ask again, whether the documentation from a single vendor should trump the specifications of an organization working on interoperability across all vendors.

Comment: You make a fair point about ibm, but what about w3 wsdl 1.1 specification?  I provided my answer according to http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_messages where it says *an alternative syntax may be used to specify the composite structure of the message using the type system directly. In this usage, only one part may be specified.* It doesn't say anything about document/literal

Comment: The spec is the spec but the purpose of WS-I is to address parts of the spec which cause Interop problems. While it is valid to just follow the spec, that doesn't guarantee interoperability. Please read the WS-I BP 1.1 document and you'll find it frequently cites cases where following the W3 spec leads to incompatible services.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I just noticed that the IBM article I referenced points out the WS-I profile non-compliance where applicable and achieves a final compliant result.  So there's no discrepancy there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found the answer.  According to specification either one is an option.
http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_messages

It seems to imply that only one part is allowed if type is used.  With element referencing many parts can be specified in the message.  However, that doesn't seem to be the case. Reference [John Saunder's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916183/265877) above for details.